# Pandas read csv - dealing with mixed named/nameless columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to open a csv file using pandas.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7xOL.png)  is a  screenshot of the file opened in excel.

Some columns have names and some do not. When trying to read this in with pandas I get the "ValueError: Passed header names mismatches usecols" error.

When I open part of the file in excel, add column names, save, and then import with pandas it works.

The problem is the files are large and cannot fully open in excel (plus I'd prefer a more elegant solution anyway).

Is there a way to deal with this issue in pandas?

I have read answers to other questions regarding this error but none were relevant.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: so you want to keep the existing column names and leave out the ones with no names as blank and open the file in pandas?

Comment: No I want to include all data, even that from columns without a name. This part was solved below but led to another issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `names` you can provide column names:

`df = pd.read_csv('pandas_dataframe_importing_csv/example.csv', names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], engine='python')`

Comment: Thank you for the response. This seems to work when I take a piece of the file but when I include the entire thing I get the following "ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 7 and found 3". Earlier in the file this method takes blank cells and treats them as "nans". For some reason later it thinks there is just no column there...this is probably a different question but please let me know if you have insight into that. Thanks!

Comment: Probably you have different amounts of commas in 7-rows and 3-rows. For sure you can parse files line by line and fix it, but I try to find direct solution in pandas.

Comment: I've added `engine='python'` in `read_csv', check if it will work for you.

Comment: This works perfectly - I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I already upvoted but it does not appear publicly since I am new here. I also did not notice that check mark until now. Thanks!